# Why haml view variable value not changing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have an issue with variables plaed in views that values are not being updated.
All values used in this view except `@last_leads` stay with same value untill i regenerate cache (in my case this means deploy using capistrano).
`@last_leads` are being refreshed correctly.

There are no `cache` tags in the view.

Any ideas?

Controller:

```rb
 class SomeClass
    def show
      lead_scope = current_provider.leads
      @today_leads = lead_scope.today
      @yesterday_leads = lead_scope.yesterday
      @earlier_this_week_leads = lead_scope.earlier_this_week
      @current_week_leads = lead_scope.current_week
      @previous_week_leads = lead_scope.previous_week
      @last_leads = lead_scope.last_ordered
    end
  end
```

View:

```
%h1 Dashboard
  .box.emphasised.clearfix

    .number-info.width-100
      .value= @today_leads.count
      Today

    .number-info.width-100
      .value= @yesterday_leads.count
      Yesterday

    .number-info.width-100
      .value= @current_week_leads.count
      This week

    .number-info.width-100
      .value= @previous_week_leads.count
      Previous week

  .box.emphasised.clearfix
      %table.generic-table.coloured.leads-list
        -@last_leads.each do |lead|
          %tr
            %td.centered= lead.created_at.to_s :short_db
            %td.cell-width-20= lead.service_choice.service.name
            %td.centered.cell-width-20= lead.phone
```

Here are the scopes:

```
 scope :today, where("leads.created_at > ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day)
  scope :yesterday, where("leads.created_at between ? AND ?", 1.day.ago.beginning_of_day, Time.now.beginning_of_day)
  scope :earlier_this_week, where("leads.updated_at between ? AND ?", Time.now.beginning_of_week, 1.day.ago.beginning_of_day)
  scope :current_week, where("leads.created_at between ? AND ?", Time.now.beginning_of_week, Time.now.end_of_week)
  scope :previous_week, where("leads.created_at between ? AND ?", 1.week.ago.beginning_of_week, 1.week.ago.end_of_week)
  scope :last_ordered, order("leads.created_at DESC").limit(5)
```

Comment: Are you sure that some unknown scope not interfering in getting results?

Comment: I've added the scopes, they should be ok.

Comment: what version of ruby and rails you are using?

Comment: rails: 3.2.8, ruby: 1.9.3-p484

Comment: please change last line to "  scope :last_ordered,  lambda{order("leads.created_at DESC").limit(5)"}  "

Comment: Can you tell me why, because the last line is the only one that gives correct values (variable is being refreshed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model get evaluated once it read so without lambda created, it will be fixed and never change. But with lambda it determine the results in runtime mean updated value.